# get custom format from Calendar using getDateTimeFormat in java

Tags: java, calendar, date-format

I have a class that extends Calendar for supporting Jalali calendar.
Currently I'm using this for formating date and time:

```
com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat df = cal.getDateTimeFormat(DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT,new com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale("fa", "IR", ""));
```

But this gives date like: `1390/09/29 17:22:10`
But i need something like: `90/09/29 17:22`
How can I do this without using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Thanks

Comment: why without using `SimpleDateFormat` ?

Comment: Why use com.ibm.* packages? Your code will not run on any other JVM implementation

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Because the my class is not extended SimpleDateFormat and using it will not generate Jalali date.

Comment: @fge: The class is written by someone else and it was the only Jalali calendar i found.

Comment: Have you considered using Joda Time?

Comment: @fge: No! can it generate Jalali Date?

Comment: I have just checked: no :/ I thought it would, though. No dice, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDateTimeFormat()` is not a method in `Calendar`, so that means it's implemented in whatever `Calendar` subclass you're using. I would expect one of the following to do what you want (just a guess, though!):

```
com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat df = cal.getDateTimeFormat(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, new com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale("fa", "IR", ""));
// or
com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat df = cal.getDateTimeFormat(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, new com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale("fa", "IR", ""));
```

That is: try passing [`DateFormat.MEDIUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#MEDIUM) or [`DateFormat.SHORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#SHORT) instead of [`DateFormat.DEFAULT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#DEFAULT).

Comment: Thanks,Time fixed But this still gives 1390/09/29 as date and not 90/09/29